# how to set selection of kendo dropdownlist via the angular model variable to which dataValueField is bound?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a kendo dropdown list in an angular app.  The dropdown is populated with data via an $http.get.

Via the config options, its `dataValueField` is bound to an integer id, and the dataTextField is bound to a string, the name associated with the integer (e.g. id = 22, name = 'Peter Piper').

Via markup, the integer in dataValueField is bound to a $scope variable,  $scope.foo:

```
      <select  kendo-drop-down-list k-ng-model="foo" ....  >
```

If  `$scope.foo` is later reassigned with a new value

```
      $scope.foo = 44;
```

how to make the  dropdownlist display the name whose id = 44?

Comment: Be sure that you update your model in $digest cycle;

I faced with almost the same problem - when you have dataSource with integer value field - the underlying ng-model int field get's replaced by string value that breaks initial binding